# How to download my application file from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have my app stored on AWS. How can i download/take down all those files to my local system from AWS ?
I know how to upload a file to aws using command line `scp` but don't know how to download from aws.

Comment: Same command, the other way around (replace the location of src/target)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use scp for downloading too.

Upload : `scp your-local-file yourId@yourAWShost:/directory/`

Download : `scp yourID@yourAWShost:/directory/filename /your/local/host/directory/`

btw if you're using ".pem" key with it, you need to add option("-i") too.

For example(Download from yourAWShost)...
`scp -i yourkey.pem yourID@yourAWShost:/directory/filename /your/local/host/directory/`

Comment: I tried ` scp -i aws.pem ubuntu@XYZ.amazonaws.com:~ /mnt/data /home/manish/AWS ` where `/mnt/data` is aws directory and `/home/manish/AWS` is my local directory here is error `scp: /home/ubuntu: not a regular file
cp: cannot stat `/mnt/data': No such file or directory
`

Comment: Because your script has white-space between ":~" and "/mnt/data". You have to remove its space. So, it should be `scp -i aws.pem ubuntu@XYZ.amazonaws.com:~/mnt/data /home/manish/AWS`

Comment: By the way, if you want to download as Directory, you need to add option "-r" too. `scp -r -i aws.pem ubuntu@XYZ.amazonaws.com:~/mnt/data /home/manish/AWS`

Comment: why its showing `scp: /home/ubuntu/mnt/data: No such file or directory`??

Comment: Because you added tilde (~). Then try `scp -r -i aws.pem ubuntu@XYZ.amazonaws.com:/mnt/data /home/manish/AWS`